# oracle what does session_id represent in *_scheduler_job_run_details

Tags: oracle

I can't understand what does `SESSION_ID` in `*_scheduler_job_run_details` represent.

There are two values separated by a coma. First one varies a lot, second one less, fe. look at below example:

```
+------+------------+
| sid  | session_id |
+------+------------+
| 6072 | 6072,8980  |
+------+------------+
```

This is selected with below query:

```sql
SELECT s.sid
    , j.SESSION_ID
FROM
   v$session s
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (select SESSION_ID
        , CAST(SUBSTR(SESSION_ID, 0, INSTR(SESSION_ID, ',')-1) as NUMBER) as ID1
        , CAST(SUBSTR(SESSION_ID, INSTR(SESSION_ID, ',')+1, LENGTH(SESSION_ID) - INSTR(SESSION_ID, ',')) AS NUMBER) as ID2
    from all_scheduler_job_run_details) j
ON j.ID1 = s.sid
    OR j.ID2 = s.sid
;
```

It seems that first number is representing `sid` from `v$session`, which accordinc to [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/dynviews_2088.htm#REFRN30223) is `Session identifier`, but so is `SESSION_ID` from `*_scheduler_job_run_details` according to [this Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10755/statviews_1140.htm). But it doesn't seem to correlate with `sql_text` from `v$sql` - if I take `sql_id` from `v$session` for this `sid`, it seems that this session was user's session that did some stuff, not my **job**.

==EDIT==

I've found out that `sid` can be reused, so it connects kind of properly. `session_id` is simply joined with newer query then the query that the job run. Still, does this other 'id' mean enything…? Could it link to some parameter of the older query, like serial# for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, session_id is `sid,serial#` - the combination is a unique identifier for a session in v$session (during the lifetime of a database instance). You can see it other places, e.g. if you need to run `ALTER SYSTEM KILL SESSION`, you have to provide it with the combined sid + serial#.

So if your job ran last week with `session_id = '6072,8980'` but somebody is currently connected in v$session with `sid = 6072 and serial# = 9504`, you can tell it's a different session, and not the same one that your job ran from.

`sql_id` in v$session simply shows *the SQL which that session is currently running* - so it will be null for INACTIVE sessions, since they aren't running right now. If your job is completed, you won't see its sql_id anywhere in v$session.